# Como obtener automáticamente el nombre de una propiedad

Tags: javascript

¡Hola! Disculpen si el título no es muy explicativo

Estoy creando un proyecto donde necesito tener varias clases de objetos, y dependiendo de ellas hacer cosas distintas. Los constructores de estas clases tienen dos propiedades, una que siempre se llama name y la otra que varía en nombre, y ahí entra mi duda

si por ejemplo tengo:

```
class Ejemplo {
   constructor(name){
     this.name = name;
     this.productos = [];
   }
}
```

y adicionalmente tengo:

```
class Ejemplo2 {
   constructor(name){
     this.name = name;
     this.ventas = [];
   }
}
```

Mi duda es con qué algoritmo puedo acceder a los distintos nombres de estos arrays, por ejemplo:

creo una variable que utilizaré para todo el documento llamada inbox como una New:

```
let inbox = new Ejemplo(prueba)
```

y luego quiero que el array que tiene (productos en este ejemplo) sea igual al que yo tengo guardado en otra parte

```
inbox.productos = arrayGuardado[i].productos;
```

Esto me funciona si siempre se fuese a llamar "productos", pero el nombre de esta propiedad cambia dependiendo de la clase que esté utilizando. Probé guardando los nombres en variables de strings y utilizarlo así:

```
let ejemplo = 'productos'

inbox.ejemplo
```

¡lógicamente no funcionó! Jaja

Como puedo resolver mi dilema? De antemano, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes acceder a la propiedad del objeto si pones el nombre entre corchetes:

```
let ejemplo = 'productos'

inbox[ejemplo]
```

El problema que presentas se resuelve mejor usando interfaces en lugar de tipos concretos, en el ejemplo, `Clase1` y `Clase2` implementan la interfaz `Base`. Luego se crea una variable de tipo `Base` en la cual se guarda una instancia de una clase concreta. Si se quiere establecer un arreglo se usa el método `setArreglo()` y si se quiere obtener el arreglo el método `getArreglo()`, a este punto no importa el nombre interno que tenga cada arreglo.

```
interface Base {
  getArreglo(): any[];
  setArreglo(arreglo: any[]);
}

class Clase1 implements Base {
  private productos: any[] = [];
  getArreglo(): any[] {
    return this.productos;
  }
  setArreglo(arreglo: any[]) {
    this.productos = arreglo;
  }
}

class Clase2 implements Base {
  private ventas: any[] = [];
  getArreglo(): any[] {
    return this.ventas;
  }
  setArreglo(arreglo: any[]) {
    this.ventas = arreglo;
  }
}

// aquí base guarda una instancia de Clase1
let base: Base = new Clase1();
// se agrega un arreglo, no importa  su nombre interno
base.setArreglo([1, 2, 3]);
// se obtiene el arreglo, no importa su nombre interno
console.log(base.getArreglo());

base = new Clase2();
base.setArreglo(["a", "b", "c"]);
console.log(base.getArreglo());
```

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero agregues una función (como el ejemplo que coloco) donde indiques cual es la otra propiedad de esa clase en particular.

De esa forma puedes asignarla como en el ejemplo se indica.

```js
/* Esto sería algo que tienes "Guardado en otra parte" */
// Estructuras para que notes el comportamiento
let algunosProductos =[
  {id:1, Nombre: "Silla"},
  {id:2, Nombre: "Mesa"},
  {id:3, Nombre: "Ventilador"},
  {id:4, Nombre: "Telefono"}
];
let algunasVentas =[
  {id:0, ProductoID:1, Cantidad:1},
  {id:1, ProductoID:1, Cantidad:2},
  {id:2, ProductoID:2, Cantidad:3},
  {id:3, ProductoID:3, Cantidad:4},
  {id:4, ProductoID:4, Cantidad:5}
];
/* Tu primer clase */
class Ejemplo1{
   constructor(name){
     this.name = name;
     this.productos = [];
   }
   
   otraPropiedad = function (){
    return "productos";
   }
}

class Ejemplo2{
   constructor(name){
     this.name = name;
     this.ventas = [];
   }
   
   otraPropiedad = function (){
    return "ventas";
   }
}

let clase1=new  Ejemplo1("Lista de productos");
let clase2=new Ejemplo2("Lista de vetnas");


console.log(/* ***** VARIABLES INICIALIZADAS ***** */);
console.log(clase1);
console.log(clase2);

clase1[clase1.otraPropiedad()]=algunosProductos;
clase2[clase2.otraPropiedad()]=algunasVentas;

console.log(/* ***** VARIABLES LUEGO DE ASIGNAR DATOS ***** */);
console.log(clase1);
console.log(clase2);
```